# H2 Database Primary Key on Create

Tags: database, h2

If I create a new tabel in my h2 database like this...

`CREATE TABLE MAININCOMER(timestamp TIMESTAMP, value REAL);`

It means that the ID will be hidden and auto increment when i write to the tabel, right? - (as far as I have learnt from the tutorial and features)

Will a Primary Key be assigned to the id *automatically*? and how important is the primary key anyway in the type of table with only 2 columns? Or should I as best practice create the table with Primary Key assigned to the timestamp?

`CREATE TABLE MAININCOMER(timestamp TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY, value REAL);`

Thanks, Alex

Comment: "*It means that the ID will be hidden*" - NO. It means your table won't have an `ID` column - not even a "hidden" one. If you want to have a column named `ID` you need to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No:** your table will not have an `ID` column, as it's not listed in your DDL `CREATE TABLE`.

The simplest way I know for adding such auto incrementing column to be used as a primary key is `ID IDENTITY`. Be careful as it's specific to H2 and not portable.

But it's so much shorter than with any other database :-D

Please change your DDL to this full line:

```
CREATE TABLE MAININCOMER(id IDENTITY, timestamp TIMESTAMP, value REAL);
```

You can test it inside H2 web console like this:

```
@loop 1000 insert into mainincomer (timestamp) values (now());
```

This will insert 1000 records and you'll see that ID is defined as a `BIGINT(19) NOT NULL`, there will be a PRIMARY KEY constraint assigned to it and it's autoincrementing nicely.

It's considered a bad practice to use timestamps as a primary key. It's hard to ensure unique constraints, as you could have event arriving at the same time (sort of, it depends on your time resolution). Plus integer are much easier to index and to find back.

Comment: Okay lets look at the bigger picture of what i am trying to achieve. I have a environment call DGLux5 here i connect to an energy meter and log data into a table when i open it, it has column row, timestamp and value. I need to store these in a database, H2 that is.  Now does my data table and H2 table not have to be identical to transfer the data? leading to my next question, how do i write multiple records from the data table to the database? With INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(..., ...),(..., ...),(..., ...), ...., (..., ...); ? In the dglux scripting environment (JavaScript) i can use

Comment: tableGetRows(@parent.table) and it gives me a result looking like this [[0,"2016-09-08T07:03:00.184","50.16"],[1,"2016-09-08T07:05:00.340","50.17"]] - how on earth would i be able to remove the row column? remove the " around the timestamp and replace it with ' and remove the " from the value to ultimately give me this INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES('2016-09-08T07:03:00.184',50.16), ('2016-09-08T07:05:00.340',50.17);

Comment: You can insert this data without using the ID: it will create the id value for you. If you need to keep the original row information I would suggest ```insert into mainincomer (original_row,timestamp,value) values (10,"2016-09-08T07:03:00.184","50.16")```

Comment: You can also insert using a select. Let imagine you wish to can have a linked table to your source data (and it's for example another h2) then you'll do ```insert into mainincomer (original_row,timestamp,value) select * from linked_table```

Comment: okay I am getting there.  I have this now insert into mainincomer values (0,"2016-09-09T06:57:37.783","50.16"),(1,"2016-09-09T06:58:37.875","50.11"),(2,"2016-09-09T06:59:37.942","50.13"); however I don't want to write the row number, this should be incremented automatically because the source data row and h2 database row will never be the same.  anyway of ignoring this row and just writing timestamp and value from the above?

Comment: so it means you do not need to store original_row number, so ```insert into mainincomer (timestamp,value) values ("2016-09-08T07:03:00.184","50.16")``` is sufficient

Comment: yes it would, but i still need to filter out the row number from my string (0,"2016-09-09T06:57:37.783","50.16"),(1,"2016-09-09T06:58:3‌​7.875","50.11"),(2,"‌​2016-09-09T06:59:37.‌​942","50.13"); before inserting into the database to get ("2016-09-09T06:57:37.783","50.16"),("2016-09-09T06:58:3‌​7.875","50.11"),("‌​2016-09-09T06:59:37.‌​942","50.13"); no idea how to get this done.

Comment: @Lexus then please change your question and add more data/code so we can help out. Both answers given answer what you asked for. If you're inserting using strings, you should use some ETL technology to avoid using strings and perform the needed filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
create table mainincomer(id bigint auto_increment,t timestamp,value real,primary key(id))
```

Comment: I don't really need a id column as I am logging data from a energy meter into a temp table that has 2 columns timestamp and value.  if i want to write this to a database table i guess these two table need to be the same.   do i need a primary key assigned to one of the columns though?

Comment: If you are using a foreign key then using either primary key or unique key is mandatory @Lexus